If you are poor and have no other option is it still haram to work in places funding israel
Pool employees who take jobs such as being waiters and cleaners dont have an option usually to work at another place but people say it is haram to work there but they have to feed there families is it actually haram to work in places like mcdonald's and kfc?

Perhaps better to ask a scholar and what regular people say will not determine the threshholds, but at least according to Shia scholars anything that make the Muslims weak or their enemies strong should be avoided.
